# Questions about the @Lazy annotation in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring

The description comment of the annotation `@Lazy` in `org.springframework.context.annotation` speaks
in the third phase :

> If this annotation is not present on a `@Component` or `@Bean` definition, eager initialization will occur

How could I comprehend this sentence?  Because it appears that a bean is lazy-initialized (which is the default behavior) but not eager initialization when a class is annotated by a single `@Component` only. While the class is annotated by a single `@Lazy` will not be the candidate because of the `component scan`

Comment: Beans are initialized eagerly, unless annotated with @Lazy.

Comment: Why does it appear that bean is lazy-intialized if its annotated only with @Component ?

Comment: "it appears that a bean is lazy-intialized (which is the default behavior)" This is incorrect. The default behaviour is eager.

Comment: I guess it all depends to what you mean with _"it appears that a bean is lazy-initialized"_?

Comment: it is lazy because I've run in a test example in debug mode and I can see the @Component class bean definition's 'lazyInit' field being set to true. Here's the stack trace :org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.class doScan method -- postProcessBeanDefinition method --beanDefinition.applyDefaults method

Comment: the ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner class has a field called beanDefinitionDefaults, it has a boolean field call  lazyInit in the BeanDefinitionDefaults class, when this object be instantiate the lazyInit boolean is always true without the setter

Comment: I think this sentence means `@Component` and `@Bean` use eager initialization strategy by default.If you want to switch to lazy initialization strategy, you can use  `@Lazy` annotation.